# How to ssh into LG webos TV

Tags: ssh, webos, lg

I can install & launch my own apps on my LG TV using e.g. `ares-install -d mytv  com.domain.app_0.0.2_all.ipk`.  But I cannot `ssh` into the system. `DevMode` status is on.

```
name            deviceinfo                    connection  profile
--------------  ----------------------------  ----------  -------
emulator        developer@127.0.0.1:6622      ssh         tv
mytv (default)  prisoner@192.168.0.111:9922   ssh         tv
```

Version details:

```
'product_name': 'webOSTV 3.5',
'model_name': 'HE_DTV_W17P_AFADABAA',
'sw_type': 'FIRMWARE',
'major_ver': '06',
'minor_ver': '10.50',
'country': 'DE',
'country_group': 'EU',
'device_id': 'xx:xx:xx:09:6f:59',
'auth_flag': 'N',
'ignore_disable': 'N',
'eco_info': '01',
'config_key': '00',
'language_code': 'de-DE'
```

But this here hangs forever, no error or timeout raised:

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/mytv_webos prisoner@192.168.0.111 -p 9922 -T`

Any ideas?  Rooting the TV is not an option.

**Edit:** (after feedback from @Kenster, thanks for that):
ssh without the -T returns:
`PTY allocation request failed on channel 0`

Here is the output from ssh wit the -vv flag:

```
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/xxx/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/xxx/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.0.111 is address
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.111 [192.168.0.111] port 9922.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/mytv_webos type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/mytv_webos-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/joXXX_id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/joXXX_id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.1
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_6.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.0.111:9922 as 'prisoner'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:5N5JLue00g+9oZYe4uI/E7DAnZLTE9XLbK/9zRbKWcg
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '[192.168.0.111]:9922' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts:33
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:b68h3BH9Hsc4zAmBriMYf+E39jvRvRP306rcCYhc5Rs explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/xxx/.ssh/mytv_webos RSA SHA256:pKgOOw3vg1ZNtvztt5x1yHQV8TYZFmlOY4lNH1abF7Q agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/xxx/.ssh/mytv_webos  explicit
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/xxx/.ssh/joXXX_id_rsa RSA SHA256:4P9clAkucxPyqENqszI6cPNXFlzmK9ZJwS0Nw0+HhxA explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:b68h3BH9Hsc4zAmBriMYf+E39jvRvRP306rcCYhc5Rs explicit agent
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/xxx/.ssh/mytv_webos RSA SHA256:pKgOOw3vg1ZNtvztt5x1yHQV8TYZFmlOY4lNH1abF7Q agent
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/xxx/.ssh/mytv_webos RSA SHA256:pKgOOw3vg1ZNtvztt5x1yHQV8TYZFmlOY4lNH1abF7Q agent
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.0.111 ([192.168.0.111]:9922).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem full
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: channel 0: setting env LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_TERMINAL = "iTerm2"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_TERMINAL_VERSION = "3.4.19"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
```

The last line repeated forever.
BTW, running on MacOS Monterey, version 12.4

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [su]. Before doing that, try running ssh without the "-T" option. If that doesn't work, run ssh with the "-vv" option to print debugging output, then include that output in your question.

Comment: What do you mean with "ssh into the system"? Aren't you able to connect to the device via ssh? How you can to install the app in that case?
I can connect to a device entirely via Ares CLI, just asking to understand properly the issue and give the correct answer if i can

Comment: This installs the app: `ares-install -d mytv` and works.  But ssh doesn't.  Maybe ssh is not supported, not sure anymore.